# Posting with an open event

Tags: vba, excel

**Action:**  Trying to 'post' excel data to a webpage that the user sees/uses with a vba code event.

**Issue:**  I can open a window with a get, or I can xmlhttp with a post and a get a response variable, but neither is what I need.   I need to POST login information (a service account) from baked in vba code on a button to POST and open a browser.

The webpage is behind Spring Security and the service account credentials should not be known to the user, it's hidden in a protected workbook/vba.  I need to post those over to the url.

--> How do I open AND post at the same time?

What I need is the excel equivalent of an HTML form post with a

```
target=_blank
```

attribute in vba. Is this possible?

I've tried both

```
ShellExecute
```

functions
and

```
xmlhttp
```

methods
but both only give me half of the package.

Any advice?

Comment: Understand that even if you protect vba in your workbook, there are always ways around it, so it should never be used to code with service account credentials. VBA is low level programming, and if you want to write something more secure, you should be using something like `VB.NET` instead and use encryption.

Comment: Send the post request with xmlhttp and store the returned cookies related to the session. Then navigate the targeted domain and set the cookies.

Comment: @braX, understood it's not the most secure thing in the world.  This is an internal corp app and requires vpn access to hit anyway.  It's mostly just to keep people from seeing it/having to type it in then it is about true security.   Florent B, that sounds possible.  Have you ever done this successfully?  I don't know how to store cookies in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to what @Florent B. has posted, check whether the cookie is set when calling the login page (which I assume) or really when posting the login data.

```
Dim xhttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP ' make sure you reference to MSXML!
Dim strCookie As String

Set xHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
XMLHttp.Open "GET" TheURLOfYourLogInPage

If xHttp.Status = 200 Then
    strCookie = xHttp.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")
End If
```

Check your web browser for what is sent to the server when login in, probably something like `"username=" & YourUserName & "&password=" & YourPassword & "&cookie=" & strCookie` Declare another string variable (I will call it strTicker) and fill it accordingly, then

```
xHttp.Open "POST", "URLOfYourLoginPage"
xHttp.setRequestHeader "Cookie", strCookie
xHttp.send strTicker
```